# GetFloatArrayElements get wrong result

Tags: c++, java-native-interface

i have searched the solution from the internet and my code look like same with other solution. i think GetFloatArrayElements is for get array element.

here is my code:

```cpp
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
    Java_draw(JNIEnv *env, jfloatArray point){
        float temp[6];
        float x = 0;

        jfloat *body = env->GetFloatArrayElements(point, 0);

        for(int i =0; i < 6 ; i++){
            temp[i] = body[i];
            x+= body[i];
            __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "TRACKERS123", "[%f]", *(body + i) );
        }

        env->ReleaseFloatArrayElements(point, body, 0);
    }
```

result is always like this:

```
[21.774231]
[0.000000]
[21.707932]
[21.776413]
[0.000000]
[0.000000]
```

i have checked the calling code from debug. here is the example value:

[image: debug]

Comment: How do you invoke this code from Java? What does the method declaration of "draw" look like?

Comment: Just : draw(point)

Comment: Void draw(float[] point)

Comment: Does `GetArrayLength` confirm that your array is 6 elements long?

Comment: No, just 1 element

Comment: Then why are you always reading six elements? Everything after the first is just random garbage.

Comment: Because i always pass 6 element of array to that method. Its guaranteed. Or any idea?

Comment: You just told me that GetArrayLength returns 1. How is that possible if you "always pass 6 elements"?

Comment: sorry. it shows 1100999584
 . 
jsize x = env -> GetArrayLength(point) ;
__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "TRACKERS123", "size %i", x );

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signature of your `Java_draw` method is wrong: [(source)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/design.html#wp715)

- The first argument is always a `JNIEnv*`.
- The second argument depends on whether the method is static or non-static:

  - If static, the second argument is a `jclass`.
  - If non-static, the second argument is a `jobject` representing the object instance.
- The third argument is your `float[]`.

So the signature should be:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_draw(JNIEnv *env, jclass klass, jfloatArray point) // static
```

or

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_draw(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jfloatArray point) // non-static
```

Comment: wow, thanks. so we must add JNIEnv and  jclass. i thought we just add what we need. and the JNI specification makes me confuse (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/jniTOC.html)

Comment: This bit was explained under the [Native method arguments](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/design.html#wp715) section.